# SUM ROWS OF VARCHAR DATATYPE or TIME DATATYPE in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

My table CalTime has a column Timespent which is of Time datatype.  It stores values in HH:MM:SS format.  Please suggest how can sum the values of this column.

```
   Timespent
    _______
    00:07:00
    01:05:00
    00:49:00
```

I want to print the total like this 02:01:00.

I wonder if there is an alternative to this using php..

P.S:  I tried doing it with php, converting each column value (in while loop ) into timestamp using strtotime and then adding them and converting them back to required format as HH:MM:SS using date('H:i:s').  That does not seem to work.  Code look something like this.

```
     <?php   while(...)
      {
      $ts += strtotime($timeCal['timespent']);
      } ?>
```

Comment: Also try the example in the php below and see if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform it in seconds, then sum it,then back to time:

```
SELECT  SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `timespent` ) ) ) AS timeSum  
FROM CalTime
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple functionality for this. You can loop through your values in an array to keep adding to the below code.

```
//Incase strtotime gives any errors
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
//
$mytime1 = "00:07:00";
$mytime2 = "01:05:00";
$secs = strtotime($mytime2)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$result = date("H:i:s",strtotime($mytime1)+$secs);
```

Psuedocode Example in a loop.

Return mysql results in the php array

```
$mytime1 = $myTimeArray[0]; 
$result = 0;

for($i=0;i<sizeOf($myTimeArray;$i++)) {
   $secs = strtotime($mytime[$i])-strtotime("00:00:00");
   $result + = date("H:i:s",strtotime($mytime1)+$secs);
}
```

Comment: for(..) { $secs += strtotime($totalTspent)-strtotime("00:00:00"); }       <?php echo date("H:i:s",$secs); ?> ..thanks for the help

Comment: upvoting the answer is also another way to thank, just saying :)